# Calculator gives TclError: wrong # args: should be ".139833730011008 insert index text"

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator, tkinter-entry

I'm new to programming and started using Python. I'm trying to do a simple calculator with 5 operations (I've only done 3 so far), that can perform PEMDAS. The problem with my code is that it worked before, but as I continually add lines I get an error on inserting in an entry.

[when performing addition + multiplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxIJd.png)

[MA() function which is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1P6I.png)

[when performing multiplication only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhces.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VnTI.png)

Here is the partial code:

```html
from Tkinter import *

main=Tk()
main.title("PEMDAS Calculator")

Grid.rowconfigure(main, 0, weight=1)
Grid.columnconfigure(main, 0, weight=1)

entry= Entry(main, width=50, bg='#DFDEDB')
label=Label(main)
frame= Frame(main)
secondFrame= Frame(main)
thirdFrame= Frame(main)
fourthFrame= Frame(main)
fifthFrame= Frame(main)

label.grid(row=1)
entry.grid(row=2, column=0)
frame.grid(row=4, column=0)
secondFrame.grid(row=5, column=0)
thirdFrame.grid(row=6, column=0)
fourthFrame.grid(row=7, column=0)
fifthFrame.grid(row=8, column=0)

#Label
intro=Label(label, text="Welcome to Calculator!")
intro.grid(row=0)

def buttons(number):
 prior= entry.get()
 entry.delete(0,END)
 entry.insert(0, str(prior)+str(number))

def addition():
 buttons('+')

def multiplication():
 buttons('*')

def subtraction():
 buttons('-')

def division():
 buttons('/')

def equal():
 eq=entry.get()
 entry.delete(0,END)
 
 if '+' and '*' in eq:
  def MA():
   while '+' in eq:
    addEl=eq.split('+')
    toMultiply=[]
    numbers=[]
    for num in addEl:
     if '*' in num:
      mulEl=num.split("*")
      for element in mulEl:
       toMultiply.append(element)
     else:
      numbers.append(int(num))
    def multiply():
     prod = 1
     for element in toMultiply:
      total = prod * int(element)
      prod = total
     return prod
    numbers.append(multiply())
    return sum(numbers)
  entry.insert(0, MA())

 elif '+' and '-' in eq:
  el = eq.split('+')
  numbers=[]
  def addsub():
   for num in el:
    if '-' in num:
     def sub():
      subEl=num.split('-')
      dif = 0
      subEl[0] = -(int(subEl[0]))
      for dig in subEl:
       dif -= int(dig)
      return dif
     numbers.append(sub())
    else:
     numbers.append(int(num))
   return sum(numbers)
  entry.insert(0, addsub())

 elif '+' in eq:
  el=eq.split('+')
  def add():
   total=[]
   for num in el:
    total.append(int(num))
   return total
  entry.insert(0, sum(add()))
 elif '*' in eq:
  def multi():
   el = eq.split('*')
   prod = 1
   for num in el:
    total=prod*int(num)
    prod=total
   return prod
  entry.insert(0, multi())
 elif '-' in eq:
  el=eq.split('-')
  def subtract():
   dif=0
   el[0] = -(int(el[0]))
   for num in el:
     dif -= int(num)
   return dif
  entry.insert(0, subtract())

 



one=Button(frame, text=1, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(1))
two=Button(frame, text=2, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(2))
three=Button(frame, text=3, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(3))
space=Label(frame, text="              ")
add=Button(frame,  padx=20, pady=20, text="+", command=addition)
subtract=Button(frame,  padx=20, pady=20, text="-",  command=subtraction)

one.grid(row=4, column=0)
two.grid(row=4, column=1)
three.grid(row=4, column=2)
space.grid(row=4, column=3)
add.grid(row=4, column=4)
subtract.grid(row=4, column=5)

four=Button(secondFrame, text=4,  padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(4))
five=Button(secondFrame, text=5, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(5))
six=Button(secondFrame, text=6, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(6))
space=Label(secondFrame, text="              ")
multiply=Button(secondFrame, text="*", padx=21.5, pady=20, command=multiplication)
divide=Button(secondFrame, text="/", padx=19, pady=20,  command=division)

four.grid(row=5, column=0)
five.grid(row=5, column=1)
six.grid(row=5, column=2)
space.grid(row=5, column=3)
multiply.grid(row=5, column=4)
divide.grid(row=5, column=5)
 
seven=Button(thirdFrame, text=7, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(7))
eight=Button(thirdFrame, text=8, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(8))
nine=Button(thirdFrame, text=9, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(9))
space=Label(thirdFrame, text="              ")
sqrt=Button(thirdFrame, text="sqrt", padx=41, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons('sqrt'))

 
seven.grid(row=6, column=0)
eight.grid(row=6, column=1)
nine.grid(row=6, column=2)
space.grid(row=6, column=3)
sqrt.grid(row=6, column=4)


space1=Label(fourthFrame, text="            ")
zero=Button(fourthFrame, text=0, padx=20, pady=20, command=lambda: buttons(0))
space=Label(fourthFrame, text="                            ")
eq=Button(fourthFrame, text="=",  padx=47, pady=20, command=equal)

space1.grid(row=7,column=0)
zero.grid(row=7, column=1)
space.grid(row=7, column=3)
eq.grid(row=7, column=5)


main.mainloop()
```

Comment: always put error message as text (in question), not image

Comment: you could format code and make 4 space indentations. And don't use nested functions - like `MA()`, `addsub()`, etc. - it is hard to find them. Put them at the beginning to better organize code.

Comment: if you have text with `*` then `if '+' and '*' in eq:` starts `MA()` but inside `MA()` you works only with `+` in `while` loop. For `*` it never runs `while` so it ends function with default `return None` so finally `entry.insert(0, MA())` means `entry.insert(0, None)` and this `None` gives error message.

Comment: Please reduce this code down to a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of extra code that's not necessary to reproduce the problem. There's just too much code for us to wad through.

Comment: With the line `while '+' in eq`, you are just allowing the function to return value if the wants multiplication operation.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the feedbacks, and I apologize for the lapses in my thread, I'm new in the community and this is my first time posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if `MA()` returns `None`. You can't insert the python value `None` into an entry widget.